# Nvidia GeForce SLI with AMD chip

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, sli

I got a set of Nvidia GeForce GTX 480's in a **NON** SLI motherboard. I was under the impression that I wouldn't need SLI to be capable of having 4 monitors.

Is this an incorrect assumption? Does my motherboard need to have SLI support to recognize both Nvidia cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Your motherboard only needs SLI support if you want to run the graphics cards in an SLI configuration (which would only allow you to drive 2 monitors, possibly 3 if you're using nVidia's Surround technology). If you just want to have two cards operating independently and driving 4 independent displays in an extended or cloned desktop configuration, then just put the cards in, hook up your monitors, and install the drivers.